# How to reset an uncontrolled Material-UI RadioButton Group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, material-ui, reset

I have several uncontrolled Material-UI RadioButton groups used in a plain old react `<form>` element.  I haven't been able to find a way to reset these radio button groups when a user clicks on the form's reset button `<button type="reset">Reset</button>`.  I'd prefer not to make these radiogroups controlled components because all the other components in these forms are also uncontrolled.

Here's a code sandbox showing an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-f09d0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The RadioButton group does not respond to the form's reset action, reverting back to the defaultValue of "female", while the Material-UI TextField does reset back to the defaultValue of "My Default Value".

Comment: By looking at your demo, it seems as if the actual input state is being changed by `reset`, but material UI is handling the styling with their internal state which isn't triggered

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I missed that when I was inspecting the source in my own project. This may actually be a legit bug.

Comment: Hey Did you solve it ? i am having the same issue here :)